# consistently grab regression coefficients when coefficients can be NA

Tags: r, lm

Consider the two `data.frames` below. In each case I want to extract the intercept, and slopes for the three variables from the associated models.

```
set.seed(911)

df1 <- data.frame(y=rnorm(10) + 1:10, x=1:10, x2=rnorm(10), x3 = rnorm(10))
model1 <- lm(y ~ x + x2 + x3, data = df1)
summary(model1)
summary(model1)$coefficients[1]
summary(model1)$coefficients[2]
summary(model1)$coefficients[3]
summary(model1)$coefficients[4]



set.seed(911)

df2 <- data.frame(y=rnorm(10) + 1:10, x=1:10, x2=1, x3 = rnorm(10))
model2 <- lm(y ~ x + x2 + x3, data = df2)
summary(model2)
summary(model2)$coefficients[1]
summary(model2)$coefficients[2]
summary(model2)$coefficients[3]
summary(model2)$coefficients[4]
```

However, in the second example there is no variation in `x2` and so the coefficient estimate is `NA`. Importantly, `summary(model2)` prints the `NA` but `summary(model2)$coefficients[3]` does not return the `NA` but skips and moves to the next parameter.

But instead I would want:

```
0.9309032
0.8736204
NA
0.5494
```

If I do not know in adnavce which coefficients will be `NA`, i.e. it could be `x1`,`x2` or `x2 &`x3`or even something like`x1`&`x2`&`x3`, how can I return the result I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grab them directly from the model. No need for using `summary()`:

```
> model2$coefficients
(Intercept)           x          x2          x3 
  0.9309032   0.8736204          NA   0.5493671
```